# Is there any way to use Android Studio in Ubuntu? If so, then how?

Tags: software-installation, android, android-studio, android-sdk

I'm new in Ubuntu. I used to work in Android Studio to develop apps.

I tried to install Android Studio, but when I went to their website, all they offered me a .zip file. I unzipped that. But I don't have any idea how to install that.

And I don't know if anyone noticed it or not, but I think, that file for Ubuntu is not full, because the file for Windows is like 1.2 GB, while Ubuntu's file is only 200MB or something... Is that alright?

Comment: Did you look at the very explicit instructions on the website?: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Click the dropdown box on the right and select Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing to install.  Just unzip the file and go to the `./bin` directory of the package and run `studio.sh`.

A common place for custom programs is the /opt directory.

So you can create a folder under /opt calling it `android-studio` or anything of your choice.  Then run the `studio.sh` from there.

If you unzip it into `/opt/android-studio` you'll have a folder in that directory called `android-studio`.  You could actually create a system-wide link to it so that you can run `studio.sh` from the commandline to start it.

To create a symbolic link perform this command:

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/android-studio/android-studio/bin/studio.sh /us/local/bin/studio.sh
```

Then to run it just type `studio.sh` from the the terminal.

Details are also included on the sdk download site:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html